# Component passed to constructor doesn't display

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, components

I've created a class that creates a panel, and in the constructor I'm passing a button with an action listener attached.
This is the code for the button:

```
JButton back = new JButton("Back");
back.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        menus.show(contentPane, "Main");
    }
});
```

It's then passed to a constructor like so:

```
lightsPane = new lightsPane(back).contents;
tasksPane = new Tasks(tasksBack).contents;
tvPane = new TV(tvBack).contents;
```

Inside the classes the button is added to a JPanel and that JPanel is then added to contents. Like so:

```
public class lightsPane{
JPanel contents;

lightsPane(JButton back){
    contents = new JPanel(new BorderLayout);

    //add back button to lower right of panel
    JPanel backPane = new JPanel();
    backPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    backPane.add(back, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    contents.add(backPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
       }
 }
```

I know the constructor is working right as when I create a button inside it to add to contents it displays fine. What's going on here? Can I pass this button to the constructor or not? If I can why isn't this displaying?

Comment: `What's going on here?` -> Absolutely no idea. Did you came here to ask some question? I think you forgot that.

Comment: I would suggest put all your code here to see what's wrong with that.

Comment: Yes ... you can *pass this button to the constructor*

Comment: @shadowmaster13 no way, no idea, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) , short, runnable, compilable and truncated about the JButtons issue

Comment: and before whatever to read tutorial about CardLayout, look for related examples on this forum (use CardLayout tag)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can pass a button to a constructor as you are passing a reference which you used in another class it is perfectly fine.

Comment: Next what do you want,  it is not clear from your asked question

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with passing the `JButton` through the constructor if it is used properly. The class either is not using it at all or is using it but in the wonge way.